# Rails Paperclip - hide link if no document is uploaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, pdf, paperclip

I am using `Paperclip` to upload documents to some (but not all records). I created a link for opening up a pdf found in records but I only want the link to be seen if there is a pdf attached.

```
<%= link_to 'Spec Sheet (PDF)', @product.document.url, :target => "_blank"%>
```

I tried variations of this:

```
<%= (link_to 'Spec Sheet (PDF)', @product.document.url, :target => "_blank") if @product.document %>
```

But I think the field is populated by `paperclip` with a `default value: 'missing.png'`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this as this worked for me:

```
 <%= (link_to 'Spec Sheet (PDF)', @product.document.url, :target => "_blank") if @product.document.exists %>
```

This will check if the document object exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

I found a great way to do this:

```
        <% if product.document.file? %>
          <%= link_to 'Spec Sheet (PDF)', product.document.url, :target => "_blank" %>
        <% end %>
```